# Protocols in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My question is: is UItextInputTraits a protocol ?? if yes why does it have instances variables ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a protocol, and no it does not have instance variables. It has properties, which are just syntactic sugar for methods.

A property does not need to be backed by an instance variable at all; not in a class definition or a protocol (in the latter it can't just by the nature of how protocols work). All it cares about is that, for instance, in the case of a protocol named `foo` two methods exist if it's `readwrite`:

```
- foo
- setFoo:
```

Obviously, returning and taking the appropriate data type.